# Solution to Cauchy Problem

Tags: cauchy-problem

I am trying to solve the following Cauchy Problem:

$y'(t) = A(t)y(t),   
A=\begin{pmatrix}
 t &-1 \\ 
 1 &t 
\end{pmatrix}, y(0)=y_0$

What I did:

I know that $ \forall\ t, s \in\ \mathbb{R}: A(s)A(t)=A(t)A(s)$

So the solution would be:

$y(t)= e^{ \begin{pmatrix}
 t^2/2 &-t \\ 
 t &t^2/2 
\end{pmatrix}} y_0$

Is that a good reasonning? Please note that I don't have more information regarding the domain of study of this Cauchy Problem so I don't know if that plays any decisive role in the solution found above.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed found the general form of a solution. See Wikipedia [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation). However , this is only true because $A$ and $A^\prime$ commute.

Comment: Thanks for useful link. I guess the condition $\forall\ t, s\ in\ \mathbb{R}: A(s)A(t)=A(t)A(s)$ is stronger than the condition $A$ and $A'$ commute, in  the sense that the first condition imply the second ?

Comment: Yes the condition you gave is stronger. You can easily derive the second by differentiating both sides of your equality in $s$and making $s=t$ afterwards.